# New Minecraft Launcher parameters and portability

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Launcher Version: 2.0.808-stage

I'm excited about the new Minecraft Launcher, and I'm hoping to put it to good use.

My goal is simple: run Minecraft from a USB without degrading it with excessive read/writes.

The [Gameband](http://gameband.com) does this automagically, but I'm dirt poor, so I made my own using the old `Minecraft Launcher.exe`.

My original setup was to set the `appdata` folder to a place on my USB so I didn't have to move all of Minecraft's resources and libraries (see [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/215082/how-to-play-minecraft-from-a-flash-drive-for-block-building-fun-anywhere/)), but all of my profiles targeted `C:\Temp\PMC` so that the saves, logs, etc that were constantly being written to were put on a hard drive to preserve the USB.

With the new launcher, it ignores the `set appdata` command, so I'm using the `--workDir` parameter instead. Then minecraft crashes before I even see the window open (the game, not the launcher). I saw [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/5opl31/help_us_test_the_new_minecraft_launcher_now_with/?st=iz0xgxuk&sh=7587c349) and it mentioned the `--lockDir` argument, so I'm trying to use that.

So far I've been able to make either everything run on the USB (not good for lifespan), or the C:\ drive (not good for copy time, because it's over 100MB on USB 2.0). I'm theorizing that I can use the `mklink` command to point the save folder on my USB to the real folder copied onto the C:\ drive, but I'm not sure. Another idea I had involves tweaking a [PortableApps Minecraft](http://portableapps.com/node/30573).

My current code is this:

```
start "" "%CD%\bin\Minecraft.exe" --workDir "C:\Temp\PMC" --lockDir "%CD%\data\.minecraft"
```

That puts everything into the C:\ drive.

Comment: But why do you tag this with "DOS"?

Comment: I'm using a Batch file to make the Launcher do stuff. Are DOS and batch files different?

Comment: Well, as it says in tag description, DOS is a family of operating systems, none of which have much in common with modern Windows. True, batch files first appeared in MS-DOS, but no, these are not the same.

Comment: 'Kay, I'll take it off. I should stop making these at 1:00 in the morning. That might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it feels humiliating answering your own question, but today, I feel quite proud of my work.

|[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lvwD9ehe5g9UQGYCXTDN96zhl13imG1B)| is PMC, short for PortableMinecraft. It's a super janky [PortableApp](http://portableapps.com) I threw together that is configured to work with Minecraft. It downloads the Minecraft Launcher so you don't have to, and it will take care of the rest. It moves files onto the C drive temporarily in order to preserve your precious USB's memory.

PLEASE read the Readme, because it has important information about how the thing works and what little issues it has.